# Validation error messages in a list (Listview)

Tags: c#, validation, listview, mvvm, idataerrorinfo

I am creating a simple application in C# MVVM and I need your help (advice). I do not know it is a possible to do but you may be know how to do it. So, to validate my textboxes I use IDataErrorInfo interface. It works pretty cool but I have one question. Is there any possibility to place error messages in a list to display in a listview? I want to avoid "\r\n" in my error messages. Thank you in advance :)

Below is my code:

Empoloyee.cs

```
public string this[string columnName]
        {
            get
            {
                int output;
                error = string.Empty;

            if (columnName == "DynamicSearchEmployeeName" && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DynamicSearchEmployeeName))
            {
                error = "Employee Name is required to add a new Employee !";
            }
            if (columnName == "DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary" && SelectedEmployee == null)
            {

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary))
                {
                    error = "Employee Salary is required to add a new Employee !\r\n";
                }
                if (!Int32.TryParse(dynamicSearchEmployeeSalary, out output))
                {
                    error += "Employee Salary has to be number !\r\nEmployee Salary cannot be less than 5 !\r\nEmployee Salary cannot be less than 10 !\r\nEmployee Salary cannot be less than 100 !";
                }
                if (Int32.TryParse(dynamicSearchEmployeeSalary, out output))
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary) || EmployeeSalary < 5)
                    {
                        error += "Employee Salary cannot be less than 5 !\r\n";
                    }
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary) || EmployeeSalary < 10)
                    {
                        error += "Employee Salary cannot be less than 10 !\r\n";
                    }
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary) || EmployeeSalary < 100)
                    {
                        error += "Employee Salary cannot be less than 100 !";
                    }
                }
            }
            if (columnName == "DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary" && SelectedEmployee != null)
            {

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary))
                {
                    error = "Employee Salary is required to add a new Employee !\r\n";
                }
                if (!Int32.TryParse(DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary, out output))
                {
                    error += "Employee Salary has to be number !\r\nEmployee Salary cannot be less than 5 !\r\nEmployee Salary cannot be less than 10 !\r\nEmployee Salary cannot be less than 100 !";
                }
                if (Int32.TryParse(DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary, out output))
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary) || Convert.ToInt32(DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary) < 5)
                    {
                        error += "Employee Salary cannot be less than 5 !\r\n";
                    }
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary) || Convert.ToInt32(DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary) < 10)
                    {
                        error += "Employee Salary cannot be less than 10 !\r\n";
                    }
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary) || Convert.ToInt32(DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary) < 100)
                    {
                        error += "Employee Salary cannot be less than 100 !";
                    }
                }    
            }
            if (columnName == "DynamicSearchEmployeeDesigner" && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DynamicSearchEmployeeDesigner))
            {
                error = "Employee Designer is required to add a new Employee !";
            }

            return error;
        }
    }
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ErrorToolTipTemplate_1">
            <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="textblockErrorTooltip" TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 0 0" />
                </Style>
            </ControlTemplate.Resources>
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="true">
                <Border Height="Auto"
   Margin="0,0,0,0"
   Background="#DC000C"
   CornerRadius="0"
   DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource textblockErrorTooltip}" 
Text="{Binding ElementName=customAdorner, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
                </Border>
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="customAdorner">
                    <Border BorderBrush="#DC000C" BorderThickness="1.3" />
                </AdornedElementPlaceholder>
            </DockPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="150" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" 
                 Value="{DynamicResource ErrorToolTipTemplate_1}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" 
Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>
```

Comment: You can always put your error messages in a `List<string>` or use a `StringBuilder` instead. You also may use `Environment.NewLine` instead of `\r\n`.

Comment: Thank you for your advice :) It works.

Answer (score 0):

Thank to Blacktempel advice I created following solution. I hope it is good.

```
        public string Error
        {
            get { return error; }
        }
        public string this[string columnName]
        {
            get
            {
                int output;
                List <string> validateErrorList = new List<string>();
                error = string.Empty;

                if (columnName == "DynamicSearchEmployeeName")
                {

                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DynamicSearchEmployeeName))
                    {
                        validateErrorList.Add("Employee Name is required to add a new Employee !");
                    }
                    if ((!Regex.IsMatch(DynamicSearchEmployeeName, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$")))
                    {
                        validateErrorList.Add("Employee Name has to contain only a-z, A-Z letters!");
                    }

                }
                if (columnName == "DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary" && SelectedEmployee == null)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary))
                    {
                        validateErrorList.Add("Employee Salary is required to add a new Employee !");
                    }
                    if (!Int32.TryParse(dynamicSearchEmployeeSalary, out output))
                    {
                        validateErrorList.Add("Employee Salary has to be number !");
                        validateErrorList.Add("Employee Salary cannot be less than 5 !");
                        validateErrorList.Add("Employee Salary cannot be less than 10 !");
                        validateErrorList.Add("Employee Salary cannot be less than 100 !");
                    }
                    if (Int32.TryParse(dynamicSearchEmployeeSalary, out output))
                    {
                        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary) || EmployeeSalary < 5)
                        {
                            validateErrorList.Add("Employee Salary cannot be less than 5 !");
                        }
                        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary) || EmployeeSalary < 10)
                        {
                            validateErrorList.Add("Employee Salary cannot be less than 10 !");
                        }
                        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary) || EmployeeSalary < 100)
                        {
                            validateErrorList.Add("Employee Salary cannot be less than 100 !");
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (columnName == "DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary" && SelectedEmployee != null)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary))
                    {
                        validateErrorList.Add("Employee Salary is required to add a new Employee !");
                    }
                    if (!Int32.TryParse(DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary, out output))
                    {
                        validateErrorList.Add("Employee Salary has to be number !");
                        validateErrorList.Add("Employee Salary cannot be less than 5 !");
                        validateErrorList.Add("Employee Salary cannot be less than 10 !");
                        validateErrorList.Add("Employee Salary cannot be less than 100 !");
                    }
                    if (Int32.TryParse(DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary, out output))
                    {
                        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary) || Convert.ToInt32(DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary) < 5)
                        {
                            validateErrorList.Add("Employee Salary cannot be less than 5 !");
                        }
                        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary) || Convert.ToInt32(DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary) < 10)
                        {
                            validateErrorList.Add("Employee Salary cannot be less than 10 !");
                        }
                        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary) || Convert.ToInt32(DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary) < 100)
                        {
                            validateErrorList.Add("Employee Salary cannot be less than 100 !");
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (columnName == "DynamicSearchEmployeeDesigner" && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DynamicSearchEmployeeDesigner))
                {
                    validateErrorList.Add("Employee Designer is required to add a new Employee !");
                }

                foreach (var validateerroritem in validateErrorList)
                {
                    error += validateerroritem+"\r\n";
                }
                error = error.ToString().TrimEnd('\r', '\n');

                if(error == string.Empty)
                {
                    IsValidated = true;
                }
                else if (error != string.Empty)
                {
                    IsValidated = false;
                }
                return error;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should split it up in multiple methods. That's way too much code for a getter inside the getter.

Comment: For each validation separated method you meant?